# Trying to get FFMPEG to merge a file list with a numbering scheme that increments by 8

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a directory of PNGs which I want to merge in to an .mp4.  The first file is named 01992000.png, the second 01992008.png, and the naming continues in increments of 8, until the final, 02018000.png.  I'm running the following command:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 60 -start_number 01992000 -i %08d.png -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -crf 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p vid.mp4
```

This creates a 1 frame long video.  I believe this is because by default ffmpeg checks for sequences with increments of 0-4, but I'm not sure of that.  In any case, I don't know how to change the increment.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use option `-pattern_type glob` and a glob pattern following the `-i` option, see [Video and Audio file format conversion](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Video-and-Audio-file-format-conversion) in the manual:

> When importing an image sequence, `-i` also supports expanding shell-like wildcard patterns (globbing) internally, by selecting the image2-specific `-pattern_type glob` option.
>
> For example, for creating a video from filenames matching the glob pattern `foo-*.jpeg`:
>
> `ffmpeg -f image2 -pattern_type glob -framerate 12 -i 'foo-*.jpeg' -s WxH foo.avi`

```
ffmpeg -framerate 60 -pattern_type glob -i '*.png' \
  -c:v libx264 -profile:v high -crf 20 -pix_fmt yuv420p vid.mp4
```

Adding `-f image2` to the command doesn't seem to have an effect, so I left it out.